# usar clases en php con solo metodos

Tags: php, mysqli, class, crud

Utilizo php y mysqli para hacer un sistema de gestión sobre una base de datos, y estoy tratando de hacer un diagrama de clases, pero no se si incluir la clase conexión. Esta posee un atributo con la conexión a mysql que hereda a otras clases, y funciones sobre la base que necesito solo con su instancia.

pero las otras clases no tienen ningún otro atributo, solo métodos de consulta, actualizar insertar y eliminar, similar a proyectos como este, pero no uso mvc:
https://github.com/ofaaoficial/php7-architecture-MVC-CRUD

Lo que sucede es que encuentro varios diagramas de clases, en los cuales casi nunca se incluyen la clase conexión. Podrían explicarme el porque?

- y usar clases con solo ese atributo es realmente POO, o sugieren algún otro enfoque?
- Este diagrama seria apropiado?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItIVM.png

Este es mi proyecto
https://github.com/Juanlgarzon/admin

Comment: Agrega aqui tu código por favor, además trata de ser mas conciso en la duda expuesta

Comment: ¿Por qué habría que incluir la conexión en una clase de tipo **entidad**.? La conexión es algo circunstancial, un medio, entre otros posibles, para obtener los datos. Imagina que pones la conexión en una clase `Persona` pero en un determinado contexto los datos con que llenarás las propiedades de la clase **no vienen de la BD**, sino de otra fuente (solicitud de API, archivo, WS, etc). Estarías obligando a `Persona` a arrastrar con la conexión siempre, aún cuando no la necesite. Una pregunta que ayudará al diseñar clases es esta: ¿Tal Entidad **nace** con esta Propiedad?

Comment: ... O, si no nace con esa propiedad, ¿la recibe al empezar a existir y le acompaña el resto de su vida? Esas serían entonces las propiedades que deberías definir en `Persona`, por ejemplo Nombre, Apellido, Fecha de Nacimiento, etc. Una persona no nace con una conexión a la BD, ni tiene por qué arrastrar toda su vida con dicha conexión porque no es parte intrínseca de su **ser `Persona`**. Dicha conexión puede ser necesitada en **algunas circunstancias**. Una de las ventajas de la POO es que permite programar y diseñar pensando en la realidad.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya cargue mi proyecto

Comment: Lo dicho por @A.Cedano denota un conocimiento profundo de diseño de sistemas basados en el paradigma POO. Excelente, de verdad. Solo añadiría: ¡Los datos son accidentales! Piensa siempre en comportamientos, y crea clases únicamente basado en esto. Si estos comportamientos necesitan ciertos datos, es allí cuando es el momento de incluirlos a las entidades. Es decir, está bien (y es, de hecho, lo correcto) tener clases con solo métodos a priori.

Comment: De esta manera, posteriormente los datos quedarán encapsulados en conjunto con las funcionalidades que realmente los necesitan. Así, se consigue apegarse a un principio fundamental de la POO, como el es el Encapsulamiento.

Comment: A partir de allí, se desprende que las clases posean una propiedad muy deseada en sistemas bien diseñados: **Alta cohesión**

Comment: Entonces estaría bien así usar las clases? solo métodos y sin atributos?

Comment: Y me refería a si debería incluir la clase conexión en el diagrama?

Comment: Es para un manual técnico y no se si hace falta incluir un diagrama de clases